# Git: revert (or rebase -i) a bad commit out of production

Tags: git, heroku, git-rebase, git-revert

We have been using [GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html) as the basis for our small development teams branching & merging off `master`. `Master` was being pushed to `staging` (for review) and then `production`. One non-approved feature got stuck on staging while a hotfix, so to speak, branched off of master and as such included the as-yet-unapproved code on staging and got pushed to `production`. Since then a few more commits have come in on top of that 'bad' commit.

*We see the need for another shared branch we can use for staging instead of assuming we could share master, but it's too late hence this question.*

I'd like to revert that "bad" commit but not sure the best way to do it. There's a lot of talk on here and elsewhere about ways to do this but because this is in production I want to make sure I understand the ramifications completely.

Pseudo git log of master branch:

```
* 2ebe3b7 2014-10-20 | merge a new_feature (HEAD, new_feature, master)
* 4483c83 2014-10-20 | add second feature (second_feature)
* 602bd9d 2014-10-20 | add premature feature (premature_feature)
* c341b06 2014-10-20 | add fileB
* b7ffb78 2014-10-20 | initial commit
```

I can either:

1. `git revert 602bd9d`
2. `git rebase -i c341b06` and rewrite my history without the offending `602bd9d` commit.

I don't have much history "rewriting history" because it's so taboo to push rewritten history to a shared Git repo.

There are collaborators and `origin/master` contains the premature code. What's the cleanest & safest way to get that single commit off of master (and thus out of production)? Looking for any advice/pitfalls.

Thanks!

Comment: My rule of thumb is - if you have more than 3 developers that would have to recover from a rebase then just do the revert.  If your developers are all competent with Git it is much less of an issue.

Comment: How involved is it to "recover from a rebase"? if it's just forcing a git pull that's ok. but if it's going to break all feature branches under development then it's probably a non-starter.

Comment: There is a section of the rebase man page called "recovering from an upstream rebase" that documents the process.   I don't personally find it difficult, but a lot of my coworkers can't do it on their own.  If you have additional branches on the server that complicates things further.  I use rebase on my unpublished work all the time, but virtually never on shared branches.

Comment: Unless there are non-technical reasons (e.g. legal reasons) why the commit can't be there, just revert it. Even if users are able to cope with a rebase, why bother? Never mind that there are good reasons why you don't want to delete code that was used in production at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just revert the commit. There is a reason why pushing rewritten history to a shared repo is "taboo"; in that case you have to make sure everybody who has ever used the repo does a `git fetch` followed by a `git reset --hard origin/master`. The only time one should push rewrites to the server is when one *needs* to, e.g. when confidential information was accidentally committed.

Comment: Revert commits can cause all sorts of merging problems later though. Say you meant to commit to branch `A` but accidentally committed to `master`. So you revert the commit on master and repush to A. Now, later when you want to merge A into master you'll have all sorts of weird unintended behavior (merge conflicts, lost code, etc) that only goes away if you first revert the revert commit on master.